# How to send request to Business Profile Performance API in Java?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

Does anyone know how I can send request to this API using Java? The link is
[Business Profile Performance API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/getDailyMetricsTimeSeries) but there is no code example. The code I tried is not correct:
supposing businessProfilePerformance is a variable of type  `BusinessProfilePerformance` to initialise global parameters via its Builder and also takes care of authorisation.

```
try {

BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries metricReport = businessProfilePerformance.locations()
                                .getDailyMetricsTimeSeries(locationName);
                        GetDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse response = metricReport.execute();
                        if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println("Response== " + response);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
```

The error is

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "details" : [ {
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
  } ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please share code of businessProfilePerformance instance?

Comment: @RaushanKumar, thanks for the reply, I cannot share the complete code since it includes my client secretkey. anyway, the initialisation is 
BusinessProfilePerformance businessProfilePerformance= new BusinessProfilePerformance.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY,
    credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Comment: as per error , it looks like you are not passing a valid locationName to this method

Comment: @RaushanKumar, no it is correct I am reading it from DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I put it here in case might serve at anyone:
supposing that the variable business_profile_performance is the initialiser global parameters via its Builder and also takes care of authentication.

```
try {

            BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries metricReport =
                    business_profile_perfomance.locations().
                    getDailyMetricsTimeSeries("My locationID" ).
                    setDailyMetric(dailyMetric).
                    setDailyRangeStartDateYear(Integer.valueOf("the desired start Year")).
                    setDailyRangeStartDateMonth(Integer.valueOf(" the desired start Month" )).
                    setDailyRangeStartDateDay(Integer.valueOf(" the desired start Day ")).

                    setDailyRangeEndDateYear(Integer.valueOf("the desired End Year" )).
                    setDailyRangeEndDateMonth(Integer.valueOf(" the desired End Month")).
                    setDailyRangeEndDateDay(Integer.valueOf("the desired End Day"));

            GetDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse response = metricReport.execute();
            if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(dailyMetric + " Response == " + response);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

the variable *dailyMetric* can be one of the metrics written in the photo below:

[image]