# How to get the metrics value in Google Business Profile Performance

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api

I was using [Google My business V4.9](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/MetricValue), I used to do

```
for (LocationMetrics locationMetrics : reportInsights.getLocationMetrics()) {
List <MetricValue> metricValue = locationMetrics.getMetricValues();
metricValue.get(0).getDimensionalValues().get(0).getValue())
```

and I was getting the value of the specific metric, but now after they have changed it to Business Profile Performance, I get a response of type `GetDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse`, I can't find any documentation that explains what is the structure of this response and how can I get the value of the metrics.

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74939379/21220008) to create the request

I can see that the new API have this object [TimeSeries](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/getDailyMetricsTimeSeries) as a response.

Comment: what is your exact problem, in the link you have shared is written the code, you need to have an active GMB profile and do the authorisations and finally put your locationId and dates

Comment: This is a response sample 
 Response ==>  {"timeSeries":{"datedValues":[{"date":{"day":13,"month":2,"year":2023},"value":"44"}]}}

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I wasn't able to create the request because of the quota limit. But still I can find it very hard stay on the same flow I had before since now I don't have the timezone specified for the data that is restored unlike the GMB V4.9 which I was able to know the timezone of the date I have, I'm afraid this will create some discrepancy between the old data and the new one.

Comment: The google response Json is completely different from the old version, I have changed even the storing table, because as you said there are changes.

Comment: @ShilaMosammami Same here... 
Have you noticed a big discrepancies in the unremoved metrics ( "MAPS_VIEWS" -> "BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_MAPS" and "BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_MAPS"  ... ) ?
I can't find anything related to the discrepancies in google's documentations.

Comment: well, yes I noticed that but I guess that is because I used to set the dates differently

Comment: @ShilaMosammami It's a bit weird, since there is no discrepancy with "CALLS_CLICKS", and in the rest of them there is a discrepancy

Comment: yes there are discrepancies